# Is there any light weight library to read pdf files from local storage for Android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-library, pdf-reader

I am working on an application where I need to show PDF files from local storage. Currently I'm using this `com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2` library to read PDF files.

After build a release apk I got surprised that - my app size increased `22.6MB` after using this library.

I have also searched in Android official docs for a better solution. I got `PdfRenderer` class. Unfortunately, this class added from API level 21. But my app minSDKVersion is 14.

How can I reduce apk size with pdf reader functionality? Or Is there any light-weight pdf library to read pdf files in Android?

Comment: open pdf with installed google doc app in phone?

Comment: Any sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative for this SDK is opening the PDF in a webview - possible solution.

Comment: `String url = "http://website.com/pdf.pdf";
        WebView  mywebview=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl(url);'

Comment: I wanted to open pdf files from local storage not from online.